# Cannot install TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow on a remote machine. I am only one of many users. The command I used (and was told to use) is:

```
pip install tensorflow --user
```

However, I got an error: "ResponseError('too many 503 error responses',)".

When I googled this error, it said it was more for HTTP requests overwhelming a server. That's not what I'm doing here, so why am I seeing this error, and how can I fix it?

```
[user@remote ~]$ pip install tensorflow --user
Collecting tensorflow
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 732, in urlopen
    body_pos=body_pos, **response_kw)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 732, in urlopen
    body_pos=body_pos, **response_kw)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 732, in urlopen
    body_pos=body_pos, **response_kw)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more times]
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 712, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(method, url, response=response, _pool=self)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/38/4a/42ba8d00a50a9fafc88dd5935246ecc64ffe1f6a0258ef535ffb9652140b/tensorflow-1.7.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (Caused by ResponseError('too many 503 error responses',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 853, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/path/python/3.6.3/core-intel1506/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 499, in send
    raise RetryError(e, request=request)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/38/4a/42ba8d00a50a9fafc88dd5935246ecc64ffe1f6a0258ef535ffb9652140b/tensorflow-1.7.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (Caused by ResponseError('too many 503 error responses',))
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with the connection. This is a stupid question, but are you sure that the machine has internet? Could it be that the firewall is blocking this connection? I'd suggest downloading it and then running the setup.py

Comment: I think it's not your fault. `503` error means `Service unavailable`, so probably server has troubles.

Comment: @ElvirMuslic I think he has Internet connection. If he doesn't he won't get 503 error code.

Comment: @Qback You're right, I didn't expect that PyPi would be down. That (almost) never happens.

Comment: @Elvir Muslic Not a stupid question! I checked, and apparently there are no issues with the machine.

Comment: @ElvirMuslic that's true..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there are issues with files.pythonhosted.org https://status.python.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think there are the same problem with pip site. I can not install anything with .

Comment: I think pythonhosted and the pip site are the same thing. Is that correct?